# Need to find the database value from greatest id available in output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, inner-join

By running the following SQL command:

```
SELECT inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id, inl_cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id, 
       inl_cbsubs_payment_items.stop_date 
FROM inl_cbsubs_subscriptions INNER JOIN 
inl_cbsubs_payment_items ON inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.id=inl_cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id 
WHERE inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id=596;
```

I get the following output:

[image]

As you can see, there are a variety of `id` values that are not always incremental.  I need a way to modify the SQL statement so that the search will filter through the results and only provide a single output from the item which has the greatest `id` value.  So, to show what I would like to see from the above example, here is a screenshot:

[image]

I am running the SQL statement in a PHP script, so if I need to implement any dynamic variables that would be available.  Thanks you for your time.

Comment: `order by user_id desc limit 1`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty you mean `order by id desc limit 1` (he wants to filter by `id` not `user_id`)

Comment: @LatheesanKanes U r correct it should be `id` not `user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a DESC sorting on id and limit result with LIMIT 1.

Comment: could you please provide an example of how I can modify my `SQL` statement in this question to do this?

Comment: `SELECT inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id, inl_cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id, 
       inl_cbsubs_payment_items.stop_date 
FROM inl_cbsubs_subscriptions INNER JOIN 
inl_cbsubs_payment_items ON inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.id=inl_cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id 
WHERE inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id=596 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;` Table name may be needed too.

Comment: works great!  I just got the lowest result though, I am going to add the sorting to see if that fixes it.